Why is SimplyBook API addClient function not working? Error log showing "Client name value is wrong"
I am trying to add a client to the SimplyBook system using JSONRCP. This is called when a new user is added to Wordpress as a subscriber using registration form built with the UserRegistration plugin.
When a user tries to register it hangs and then throws an error saying "Client name is wrong". I have tried hard coding some dummy data in and this does work. So it seems that there is an issue with getting the data from the database using the function "$first_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);"
Any suggestion on what I may be doing wrong would be very much appreciated!
/* Function to run when a new user is created */
function sync_user_created($user_id) {

    $user_id = reset($user)->ID;

    // Get user data
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

    // Check if the user has the role of 'subscriber'
    if (in_array('subscriber', $user_info->roles)) {

        $first_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);
        $user_email = get_userdata($user_id, 'user_email');
        $user_phone = get_user_meta($user_id, 'phone', true);

        // authenticate connection - this function works
        $JsonRcpClient = SimplyBookAdminAuth();
    
        $clientData = array(
            'name' => $first_name,
            'email' => $user_email,
            'phone' => $user_p  hone
        );

        // add the new client to SimplyBook database - don't send an email
        $JsonRcpClient->addClient($clientData, false);
    
    }

}
// hook into new user registration
add_action('user_register', 'sync_user_created');

The error I am getting from the UserRegistration log is:
2024-10-18T13:05:18+01:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Exception: Request error: Client name value is wrong in C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-content\themes\understrap-child\includes\JsonRpcClient.php:57Stack trace:#0 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-content\themes\understrap-child\includes\sb_client_sync.php(35): JsonRpcClient->_call('addClient', Array)#1 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(326): sync_user_created('861')#2 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)#3 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)#4 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\meta.php(336): do_action('updated_user_me...', '861', 50, 'first_name', 'Adam')#5 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\user.php(1217): update_metadata('user', 50, 'first_name', 'Adam', '')#6 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-content\plugins\user-registration\includes\frontend\class-ur-frontend-form-handler.php(253): update_user_meta(50, 'first_name', 'Adam')#7 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-content\plugins\user-registration\includes\frontend\class-ur-frontend-form-handler.php(123): UR_Frontend_Form_Handler::ur_update_user_meta(50, Array, 167)#8 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-content\plugins\user-registration\includes\class-ur-ajax.php(296): UR_Frontend_Form_Handler::handle_form(Array, 167)#9 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(324): UR_AJAX::user_form_submit('')#10 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)#11 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)#12 C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php(207): do_action('wp_ajax_nopriv...')#13 {main}thrown in C:\wamp64\www\Gruffs\wp-content\themes\understrap-child\includes\JsonRpcClient.php on line 57


https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/: "Not all user meta data has been stored in the database when this action is triggered. For example, nickname is in the database but first_name and last_name are not (as of v3.9.1)" Maybe you should rather look for this information in the $userdata array the callback function gets passed as second parameter, than trying to fetch it from the database. Or you will have to use some "later" hook.

thanks for the help. I did eventually figure this one out. Here is the code for the working function. I was using the wrong hook and some errors in the code also needed fixing. The hook to use when using the UserRegistration plugin is the one below, not "user_register".
/* Function to run when a new user is created */
function sync_user_created( $valid_form_data, $form_id, $user_id ) {

    // Get user data
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

    // Check if the user has the role of 'subscriber'
    if (in_array('subscriber', $user_info->roles)) {

        $first_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);
        $last_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', true);
        $user_email = get_userdata($user_id)->user_email;
        $user_phone = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_registration_phone_number', true);

        // authenticate connection - this function works
        $JsonRcpClient = SimplyBookAdminAuth();
        
        $clientData = array(
            'name' => $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
            'email' => $user_email,
            'phone' => $user_phone
        );

        // add the new client to SimplyBook database - don't send an email
        $JsonRcpClient->addClient($clientData, false);
        
    }
    
}
// hook into new user registration when UserRegistration form is used
add_action('user_registration_after_register_user_action', 'sync_user_created', 10, 3);

Hope that helps anyone else running into this issue.
